# How to get where a foreign key was used across all the database in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql database where I have a table named media, and multiple tables each have media_id as a foreign key,

I want a query to return the table where a specific media_id is used.

Comment: You'll have to query each table separately. You may be able to do all the tables in a single SQL statement via UNION ALL, but sad to say there's no arcane magic that lets us ask, which tables mention this particular value in this particular column in this particular table.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use system tables.

```
SELECT
  object_name(parent_object_id) ParentTableName,
  object_name(referenced_object_id) RefTableName,
  name 
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('Tablename')
```